# Handbrake problem

Tags: audi, a4

The handbrake seems too loose, it used to be normal when you pull it up, you can feel the force from the brake, but it suddenly becomes very loose, and I could literally pull it all the way up. But when I pull it up, the brake light is still on, and pull it down the light turns off.
I am not sure it is broken or it is loose. Please take a look of the attached picture.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: If it has rear drum brakes, they may need adjusting.

Answer (score 3):

This suggests that the handbrake cable has stretched or snapped.

It needs replacing.

The light is operated by a switch close to the handbrake lever so is independent to the cable issue.

Answer (score -1):

When this happens its most probably a snaped cable and the cable usually fails on the point where it separates into two parts or rarely right in the middle